# Why does _VERSION return "Luau" instead of "Lua 5.1" and why does += operator suddenly work?

Tags: lua

I found out the _VERSION returns `"Luau"` instead of `"Lua 5.1"`. I also found out `continue` and the `+=` operator works

```lua
print(_VERSION) -- Luau
value = 0
value += 1
print(value) -- Doesn't return a syntax error
for k, v in ipairs({1, 2, 3, 4}) do
  if k == 1 then
    continue -- This works?
  end
  print(v)
end
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
```

I also messed around with it and realized type annotation works.

```
function foo(x: number, y: string): boolean
    local k: string = y:rep(x)
    return k == "a"
end
```

doesn't throw a syntax error.
I also found out `table.find`, `table.create` and `math.clamp` is removed in Lua 5.4 as well as `typeof` function

I also realized binary literal `print(0b10)` returns `2` in Lua 5.1 but throws an error in Lua 5.4, along with `print(1_000)` which returns 1000 in Lua 5.1, but doesn't work in Lua 5.4

Why does these suddenly work on Lua 5.1? Did not expect it to work Lua 5.1
When I switched to Lua 5.4, _VERSION returns `"Lua 5.4"` instead and `continue` doesn't work and `typeof` was removed (How do I check types in Lua 5.4?).
What's going on?
And why does Lua 5.4 remove the += , continue operator and why does _VERSION return Luau in Lua 5.1?

Comment: What was the context where you tried these things? (Many of those things have never been part of Lua, only features of Luau.)

Answer (score 5):

Simple as: it's **not** Lua 5.1.

It's [Luau](https://roblox.github.io/luau/), a language derived from Lua 5.1 and [backwards-compatible](https://luau-lang.org/compatibility) with it. That's why your usual 5.1 code works, and why you can use some new features. Luau is maintained by Roblox. Its [source code](https://github.com/Roblox/luau) is published under MIT license.

As for Lua 5.4, see its [Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/contents.html) to know what to expect from it.